# Avoiding repeated legend in seaborn boxplot overlaid by swarmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

[image]

In the seaborn based plot below, I am making a box plot overlaid by a swarm plot. Both are subset by hue. Is there any way I can not have them repeated twice in the legend though?

Here is my code:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=name_xaxis, y=name_col, hue=hue, data=frame, palette='Set2', linewidth=1.5, width=0.5)
sns.swarmplot(x=name_xaxis, y=name_col, hue=hue, data=frame, palette='Set2', color='.25', split=True)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to add this after `sns.swarmplot(...)`:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2])
```

This should replace the legend with only two entries from existing one.

Comment: You're a darn legend!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer afresh every time I stumble upon it!